# Run BlockUI on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I run the BlockUI plugin (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos) when the page loads? I modified it so that when you **click** the `body` tag it runs the plugin, but I want that to happen when the page loads...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('body').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff' 
        } }); 

        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: As an aside: BlockUI also supports something called "auto unblock". You can pass in the parameter `timeout` when you call `$.blockUI` and specify the number of milliseconds before automatically unblocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take it out of the click method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    blockUI({ parameters });
    setTimeout...
    $('body').click...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked. I also added the `setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);` to unblock the page.

Comment: Aye. Just make sure you have a setTimeout in the document.ready as well as the body.click :)

Answer (score 1):

take it out from that click event (or copy-paste (or use function - the best one))

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.blockUI({ css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff' 
    } }); 
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
    $('body').click(function() {
        $.blockUI({ css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff' 
        } });  
        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000);
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Also worked, and the `setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); ` needs to be below the `$.blockUI` function to unblock the page.